# IOS - CoreData - Insert new entity with already inserted relation entity

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data

I've 2 entities: Mother and Child.
Mother have it's properties and other that a NSSet as childs.
Child have it's property and other that a Mother property. 
So there is Relation 1-n:
Now, the Mother is already saved and persiste
d. I need to insert a new child, so I try with the code:

```
-(void)addChild:(NSString *)name {
    // get Child instance to save
        Child *child = (Child*) [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Child" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
        mother

        // get Mother element to associate
        NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
        NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Mother" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
        [request setEntity:entity];
        NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"mother_desc = %@", @"themothertofind"];
        [request setPredicate:predicate];

        id sortDesc = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"mother_desc" ascending:YES];
        [request setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDesc]];

        NSError *error = nil;
        NSArray *fetchResults = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
        if (fetchResults == nil) {
            NSLog(@"%@", [error description]);
        }
        else {
        // id mother exist associate to Child
            [child setMother:[fetchResults objectAtIndex:0]];
            NSLog(@"Mother: %@", Child.mother.mother_desc);
        }


        [child setName:name];

        if (![self.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"%@", [error description]);
        }
}
```

With the log I see the consistency of all data.
Unfortunately i receive a constraint exception (19). Like if the CoreData try to save again Mother object.
Someone can see where is the error in the code?

Thanks!

```
@class Mother;

@interface Child : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) Mother *mother;

@end
```

---

```
@class Child;

@interface Mother : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *children;
@end

@interface Mother (CoreDataGeneratedAccessors)

- (void)addChildrenObject:(Child *)value;
- (void)removeChildrenObject:(Child *)value;
- (void)addChildren:(NSSet *)values;
- (void)removeChildren:(NSSet *)values;

@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the problem:

In the table zchild I've added records without using CoreData.

This cause the table z_primarykey (a table auto generated by CoreData) was not updated. In the specific, there is a column "z_max" that must contains the next id to use for the next insertion. In my case those z_max are equals to the id of child already in table and that's the constraint violation.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than set the mother property of the child managed object, add the child to the Mother managed object's set of children.  But be aware you cannot simply get a reference to the set and add it, you need to use the appropriate methods.

The Mother managed object, assuming you set up you model correctly, should have a method along the lines of addChildObject: or addChildrenObject:.

So in the code would look something along nthe lines of:

```
Mother *mother=[fetchResults objectAtIndex:0];
NSLog(@"mother:  %@, mother);
[mother addChildrenObject: child];
NSLog(@"Mother: %@", child.mother.mother_desc);
```

Note that I made a correction to your original NSLog statement.  You were actually asking for a description from the class, not the in instance of the child object.

Either way, when using the Mother managed object's method for adding items to its children set, Core data will also setup the reverse relationship of the child's mother property.

good luck.

Tim

Comment: i've try to replace setMother() with addChildObject() of the Mothers entity like you suggest, but still: CoreData: error: (19) constraint failed... help!

Comment: Please post the .h files for your Child and Mother objects.

Comment: The class are auto generated with Xcode, I've post the code, thanks for helping.

Comment: I've find the problem:

In the table zchild I've added records without using CoreData. 

This cause the table z_primarykey (a table auto generated by CoreData) was not updated. In the specific, there is a column "z_max" that must contains the next id to use for the next insertion. In my case those z_max are equals to the id of child already in table and that's the constraint violation.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Good. It looks like you hit upon the holy grail of Core Data no no's. don't modify the data base yourself.  If my answer fixed your original question, please accept it.

Comment: I've to load in the db very very much data, so I prepare a DB already populated to deploy with app. Many thanks for help, I'll giving an up to your reply, but the constraint violation isn't from code error (the code still run with original version), so I prefere to not accept, may be someone with the same problem have to find the right solution. Many thanks